Ordering a dict in javascript keys are float
I am trying to order this that use key, values. Both are floating numbers.
{
  '2023.4': '665999.91',
  '2023.5': '1228000.0',
  '2023.6': '643842.86',
  '2023.7': '510166.67',
  '2023.8': '727600.0',
  '2023.9': '535327.63',
  '2024.1': '472591.88',
  '2024.2': '525736.46',
  '2024.3': '596570.0',
  '2024.4': '548539.52',
  '2023.10': '562607.69'
}

My solution is not working and  I hit a wall on this one...
// Convert object to array of objects
const dataArray = Object.entries(trends).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

// Sort the array based on the formatted keys
dataArray.sort((a, b) => {
  const keyA = Object.keys(a)[0];
  const keyB = Object.keys(b)[0];
  const [yearA, monthA] = keyA.split('.').map(part => parseInt(part));
  const [yearB, monthB] = keyB.split('.').map(part => parseInt(part));
  
  if (yearA === yearB) {
    return monthA - monthB;
  } else {
    return yearA - yearB;
  }
});

// Reassign the sorted values back to the original object
dataArray.forEach((item,`your text` index) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  trends[key] = Object.values(item)[0];
});

console.log(data)

Order a javascript dict - array

Code that relies on property name ordering is very fragile and generally (that is, almost always) a really bad idea.

You’re trying to order the object? It might be better to use an array/list collection to represent an ordered collection.

When reassigning object props their order stays the same, you need to add them (to a new object):


const input = {
  '2023.4': '665999.91',
  '2023.5': '1228000.0',
  '2023.6': '643842.86',
  '2023.7': '510166.67',
  '2023.8': '727600.0',
  '2023.9': '535327.63',
  '2024.1': '472591.88',
  '2024.2': '525736.46',
  '2024.3': '596570.0',
  '2024.4': '548539.52',
  '2023.10': '562607.69'
}

const transformKey = key => key.replace(/\.(\d)$/, '.0$1');

const result = Object.keys(input)
  .sort((a, b) => (a = transformKey(a), b = transformKey(b), a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0))
  .reduce((r, key) => (r[key] = input[key], r), {});

// if you need to mutate the original object:
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input).forEach(name => delete input[name]);
Object.assign(input, result);

console.log(input);



But using an object for ordered data is a bad idea. The most hated by me is that you can't use array methods on an object.
As soon as you introduce positive integers you have them ordered asc and before alpha-starting props:


const obj = {
  'alpha': 1.0,
  '2004': 1.2,
  '2003': 1.1
};

console.log(obj);



To preserve the order with positive integers you could consider to use a custom class:


const Obj = new Proxy(Object, {
  apply(_, __, args){
    return new Obj(...args);
  },
  construct(_, args){
    const obj = Reflect.construct(...arguments);
    const map = new Map;
    
    for(const arg of args){
      for(const key in arg){
       map.set(key, arg[key]);
      }
    }
    
    return new Proxy(obj, {
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_, prop) {
        return { configurable: true, enumerable: true, value: map.get(prop) };
      },
      ownKeys(){
         return [...map.keys()];
      },
      get(_, prop){
        if(prop === Symbol.iterator){
          return map.keys.bind(map);
        }
        if(prop in obj){
          return obj[prop];
        }
        return map.get(prop);
      },
      set(_, prop, value){
        map.set(prop, value);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

});

const input = Obj({
  '2023.4': '665999.91',
  '2023.5': '1228000.0',
  '2023.6': '643842.86',
  '2023.7': '510166.67',
  '2023.8': '727600.0',
  '2023.9': '535327.63',
  '2024.1': '472591.88',
  '2024.2': '525736.46',
  '2024.3': '596570.0',
  '2024.4': '548539.52',
  '2023.10': '562607.69'
});

const transformKey = key => key.replace(/\.(\d)$/, '.0$1');

const result = Object.keys(input)
  .sort((a, b) => (a = transformKey(a), b = transformKey(b), a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0))
  .reduce((r, key) => (r[key] = input[key], r), Obj());

// if you need to mutate the original object:
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input).forEach(name => delete input[name]);
Object.assign(input, result);

console.log(input);



The next move would incorporate the sorting in the class, so you could do just:
input.sortKeys(key => key.replace(/\.(\d)$/, '.0$1'));



class Sortable{
  sortKeys(cb){
    const result = Object.keys(this)
      .sort((a, b) => (a = cb(a), b = cb(b), a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0))
      .reduce((r, key) => (r[key] = input[key], r), new Sortable);
    // if you need to mutate the original object:
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach(name => delete this[name]);
    Object.assign(this, result);
    return this;
  }
}

const Obj = new Proxy(Sortable, {
  apply(_, __, args){
    return new Obj(...args);
  },
  construct(_, args){
    const obj = Reflect.construct(...arguments);
    const map = new Map;
    
    for(const arg of args){
      for(const key in arg){
       map.set(key, arg[key]);
      }
    }
    
    return new Proxy(obj, {
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_, prop) {
        return { configurable: true, enumerable: true, value: map.get(prop) };
      },
      deleteProperty(_, prop){
        map.delete(prop);
        return true;
      },
      ownKeys(){
         return [...map.keys()];
      },
      get(_, prop){
        if(prop === Symbol.iterator){
          return map.keys.bind(map);
        }
        if(prop in obj){
          return obj[prop];
        }
        return map.get(prop);
      },
      set(_, prop, value){
        map.set(prop, value);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

});

const input = Obj({
  '2023.4': '665999.91',
  '2023.5': '1228000.0',
  '2023.6': '643842.86',
  '2023.7': '510166.67',
  '2023.8': '727600.0',
  '2023.9': '535327.63',
  '2024.1': '472591.88',
  '2024.2': '525736.46',
  '2024.3': '596570.0',
  '2024.4': '548539.52',
  '2023.10': '562607.69'
});

input.sortKeys(key => key.replace(/\.(\d)$/, '.0$1'));

console.log(input);




Tangential, but JS objects preserve insertion order by spec. So while it’s still the wrong structure, as of ES6 (?) you could use a POJSO ‍♂️

sorted_keys = sorted(cohort_avg_prices.keys(), key=lambda x: (int(x)))
Define a function to extract the numeric part and convert it to a sortable format
def get_sortable_key(key):
if len(key) == 1:
key = '0' + key
# Convert to a sortable format, e.g., YYYYMM
return f"{key}"

Create a new dictionary with sorted keys
sorted_dictionary = {key: cohort_avg_prices[key] for key in sorted_keys}cohort_avg_prices_dict = dict(list(sorted_dictionary.items())[-11:])
